# (2D) Take player speed into account while shooting bullets

Tags: unity

In my top down 2D game, there is a plane as shown below:

[image]

The plane shoots bullets forward. For firing bullets, I use:

```cs
obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.up*500);
```

However, when player presses up arrow or A key, plane speed increases. At this point, bullets are slower than the plane and appear to move backwards when plane moves at maximum speed.

How do I take into account player speed so that force applied takes into account player speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lacking of code, however I would suggest that the bullet `obj` is a result of the method `Instantiate`. If it so, you should just inherit velocity of the plane right after instantiation and before adding force.

```cs
GameObject obj = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, plane.tranform.position, plane.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
Rigidbody2D rb2d = obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
rb2d.velocity = plane.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity;  // set bullet's velocity equal to 'source' velocity
rb2d.AddForce(transform.up * 500);  // and then add force
```

Also, you can play around with [ForceMode2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode2D.html) and optionally try [Rigidbody2D.AddRelativeForce](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddRelativeForce.html) to get desired/unusual effects.

Comment: Inheriting parent velocity was the key